# How to get content from one file, that contains in another file

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

How to get rows from one file, that contains in another file

Example, i have

```
// first
foo
bar
```

```
// second
foo;1;3;p1
bar;1;3;p2
foobar;1;3;p2
```

This files are big, first file contain ~ 500 000 records, and second ~ 20-15 millions

I need to get this result

```
// attention there is no "p1" or "p2" for example
foo;1;3
bar;1;3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it wants the `join` command, possibly with sorting.  But with millions of records, it's time to think seriously about a real DBMS.

```
join -t\; -o 0,2.2,2.3 <(sort -t\; -k 1,1 first) <(sort -t\; -k 1,1 second)
```

(This requires `bash` or `zsh` for the `<(command)` syntax; portably, you would need to sort into temporary files or keep the input files sorted.)

Answer (score 1):

[grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) -f:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty  file
          contains  zero  patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

[cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) -d\; -f1-3:

```
-d, --delimiter=DELIM
          use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

-f, --fields=LIST
          select only these fields;  also print any line that contains  no
          delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
```

Putting it together: `grep -f pattern_file data_file | cut -d\; -f1-3` .

Comment: That won't satisfy the `// attention there is no "p1" or "p2" for example`.

Comment: `grep -f` not works, for me it return only the last matched string